# Vue.js v-bind class with condition always true when in deployment

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a simple to-do list app with Laravel and Vue.js. The conditional class binding `v-bind:class="[{'todo-list__item-checked': todo.complete}]"` in the code below works just fine on localhost for both dev and production mode. Once I deployed it to online server the class `todo-list__item-checked` is always set, no matter what the `todo.complete` value is. I double-checked that the `todo.complete` value is correct. It is either 0 or 1.  It is the same thing for the checkbox input (always checked).

```
<ul class="todo-list text-left">
    <li v-for="todo in nonNullTodos" v-bind:key="todo.id" :id="'todo_'+todo.id" class="edit-item-icon-parent">
      <div class="list-item">
        <label :for="todo.id" class="list-label" role="button"> <input type="checkbox" v-model="todo.complete" :id="todo.id" @click="toggleComplete(todo.id)"> <span class="todo-list__text" v-bind:class="[{'todo-list__item-checked': todo.complete}]" :id="'todo_name_'+todo.id">{{ todo.name }}</span></label>
      </div>
      <div class="list-action">
        <i class="fa fa-pencil edit-item-icon" @click="editTodo(todo.id)"></i>
        <delete-button :item-id="todo.id" :item-type="'todo'"></delete-button>
      </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I can't seem to figure out the issue. Any help is appreciated . Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if it has something to do with the problem but it should be `v-bind:class="{'todo-list__item-checked': todo.complete}"` without the brackets

Comment: Thanks for your comment @SélimAchour .  Kian's answer solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the value of `todo.compelete` is typeof number. If it's '0', it will be convert to `true`. It's better to use boolean type `true` or `false`.

And there is no problem to use array for `:class` to define multiple classes. (reply Sélim Achour)

Comment: Thanks @Kian :) This solved the problem. I had to convert the value of 'complete' to boolean.